# Pointer to (data) member as non-type template parameter for instance with automatic storage duration / without linkage

Tags: c++, templates, pointer-to-member

Consider the following snippet:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    Foo() : foo_(0U), bar_(0U) {}

    void increaseFoo() { increaseCounter<&Foo::foo_>(); }
    void increaseBar() { increaseCounter<&Foo::bar_>(); }

    template <uint8_t Foo::*counter>
    void increaseCounter() { ++(this->*counter); }

    uint8_t foo_;
    uint8_t bar_;
};

void callMeWhenever() {
    Foo f;  // automatic storage duration, no linkage.
    f.increaseFoo();
    f.increaseFoo();
    f.increaseBar();

    std::cout << +f.foo_ << " " << +f.bar_;  // 2 1
}

int main() {
    callMeWhenever();
}
```

My first guess would've been that this was ill-formed, as `f` in `callMeWhenever()` has automatic storage duration, and its address is not known at compile time, whereas the member template function `increaseCounter()` of `Foo` is instantiated with pointers to data members of `Foo`, and the memory representation of a given class type is compiler specific (e.g. padding). However, from [cppreference / Template parameters and template arguments](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters), afaics, this is well-formed:

> *Template non-type arguments*
>
> The following limitations apply when instantiating templates that have non-type template parameters:
>
> [..]
>
> [*until C++17*] For pointers to members, the argument has to be a pointer to member expressed as `&Class::Member` or a constant expression that evaluates to null pointer or `std::nullptr_t`value.
>
> [..]
>
> [*since C++17*] The only exceptions are that non-type template parameters of reference or pointer type [*added since C++20: and non-static data members of reference or pointer type in a non-type template parameter of class type and its subobjects (since C++20)*] cannot refer to/be the address of
>
> - a subobject (including non-static class member, base subobject, or array element);
> - a temporary object (including one created during reference initialization);
> - a string literal;
> - the result of typeid;
> - or the predefined variable `__func__`.

How does this work? Is the compiler (by direct or indirect, e.g. the above, standard requirements) required to sort this out by itself, storing only (compile-time) address offsets between the members, rather than actual addresses?

I.e./e.g., is the compile time pointer to the data member non-type template argument `counter` in `Foo::increaseCounter()` (for each of the two specific pointer to data member instantations) simply a compile time address offset for any given instantiation of `Foo`, that will later become a fully resolved address for each instance of `Foo`, even for yet to be allocated ones such as `f` in the block scope of `callMeWhenever()`?

Comment: The "since C++17" part quoted looks fishy. For information, the latest [draft of the Standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.nontype#3) allows a non-type template parameters of pointer type being the address of a non-static class member.

Comment: @YSC thanks; I omitted, perhaps confusingly, the C++20 part from my quote: _"and non-static data members of reference or pointer type in a non-type template parameter of class type and its subobjects (since C++20)"_. Updated my question with the full quote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is the compiler (by direct or indirect, e.g. the above, standard requirements) required to sort this out by itself, storing only (compile-time) address offsets between the members, rather than actual addresses?

Pretty much. It's an "offset" even outside of a compile time context. Pointers to members are not like regular pointers. They designate members, not objects. That also means that the verbiage about valid *pointer* targets does not relate to pointer-to-members.

That's why to produce an actual lvalue out of them, one must complete the picture with something that refers to an object, such as we do in `this->*counter`. If you were to try and use `this->*counter` where a constant expression is required, the compiler would have complained, but it would have been about `this`, and not `counter`.

Their distinct nature is what allows them to uncondionally be compile time constants. There's no object that the compiler must check as a valid target.

Comment: I see, thanks. _"Pointers to members are not like regular pointers. They designate members, not objects."_ - does it make sense to speak of pointers to data members as `constexpr` then? And, if so, do you know if the standard  (somewhat) explicitly describes this somewhere?

Comment: @dfri - Thought you might ask, so I checked. A constant expression in the standard is defined by what it cannot be, as opposed to what it is. So when you write `&Foo::foo_`, you get a prvalue that designates the member. That prvalue, when places in a context that requires a constant expression, undergoes a [gauntlet of checks](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.const#2). Only that which passes the checks, is a constant expression.

Comment: Ah I see, that _"by exclusion of other"_-standardese explains why I had such a hard time sorting this question out by means of the standard and myself prior to posting it here. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As StoryTeller already mentioned, pointer to members are different from normal pointers. If we take a look at the (almost) unoptimized assembly generated by clang (full code [here](https://godbolt.org/z/iaz1Zu)) we see the instantiations of the template:

```
void Foo::increaseCounter<&Foo::foo_>(): # @void Foo::increaseCounter<&Foo::foo_>()
        add     byte ptr [rdi], 1 
        ret

void Foo::increaseCounter<&Foo::bar_>(): # @void Foo::increaseCounter<&Foo::bar_>()
        add     byte ptr [rdi + 1], 1
        ret
```

Since those are member functions `rdi` (which is the first function argument) holds a pointer to the class instance (`this` in our case). Because `Foo::foo_` is the first member, it's address matches with its class, so `&f== &f.foo_` (where `f` is an instance of `Foo`). So for `Foo::foo_` we simply take the address of `this` and increment the byte to which this address is pointing by 1.

The 2nd case is similar. The only difference is that `Foo::bar_` is the second data member in the class and since `Foo::foo_` takes only 1 byte of space, `Foo::bar_` is located at `reinterpret_cast<char*>(this) + 1` which is reflected by the `rdi + 1`.

Comment: A nice addendum to StoryTeller's answer, thank you.