# Pointer to a member function does not contain the information of the instance?

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers

<sub>(This is a question after reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2402607/10027592))</sub>

I tried this code:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
 int a;
 A(int val) : a{val}{}
 int f(int);
 int (A::*p)(int);
};

int A::f(int in) {
 return in + a;
}

int main() {
 A a1(1000);
 A a2(2000);
 
 // Without these two lines, segmentation fault.
 a1.p = &A::f; // no instance information.
 a2.p = &A::f; // no instance information.
 
 std::cout << a1.p << " " << a2.p << '\n';
 std::cout << std::boolalpha << (a1.p == a2.p) << '\n';
 
 std::cout << (a1.*(a1.p))(5) << '\n';
 std::cout << (a1.*(a2.p))(5) << '\n';
 std::cout << (a2.*(a1.p))(5) << '\n'; 
 std::cout << (a2.*(a2.p))(5) << std::endl;
}
```

Results:

```
1 1
true
1005
1005 // the same result as above.
2005
2005 // the same result as above.
```

1. It seems that `a1.p` and `a2.p` are the same. Is the member function's address **not** assigned until it is dereferenced and called by attaching the instance's name?
2. If so, what's the point of assigning `&A::f`, if it has no information about the instance?

Comment: (1) Member function's address doesn't depend on which instance it's called on. Non-static member functions are effectively free functions with a hidden `this` parameter, they are not duplicated per instance. (2) To be able to call it on any instance? You can combine it with a specific instance pointer using `std::bind_front` or a custom lambda.

Comment: 2) To identify the member member `f` with the pointer `p`. The information about the instance will be provided when dereferencing the pointer `p`.

Comment: Related/possible dupe: [Pointer to (data) member as non-type template parameter for instance with automatic storage duration / without linkage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59665325/pointer-to-data-member-as-non-type-template-parameter-for-instance-with-automa)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-static member functions have a "hidden" first argument that becomes the `this` pointer inside the function. So instance is not part of the function itself, but rather passed as an argument.

Note the quotes around "hidden", because it's only hidden in the function signature. When using other ways to call e member function, it's not really hidden but actually passed like any other argument. For example if using `std::bind` or `std::thread`, non-static member function are called with the instance as an actual argument.

Example:

```
struct thread_class
{
    int value_;

    explicit thread_class(int value)
        : value_{ value }
    {
    }

    void thread_func(int arg)
    {
        std::cout << "arg is " << arg << '\n';
        std::cout << "value is " << value_ << '\n';
    }
};

int main()
{
    thread_class foo;
    std::thread thread(&thread_class::thread_func, &foo, 123);
    thread.join();
}
```

The three arguments to the `std::thread` constructor is the function to run, and the arguments to the function itself. The first is the object to call the function on, what becomes `this` inside `thread_func`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Then maybe I can think `(a1.*(a1.p))(5);` as if `(*(a1.p))(&a1, 5)`, using the `&a1` as the first argument? If so, is there any reason the language doesn't use this simple way?

Comment: @starriet It's *similar* to that, but it's not allowed because function-pointers doesn't work like that.

Answer (score 2):

> It seems that a1.p and a2.p are the same. *Is the member function's address not assigned until it is dereferenced and called by attaching the instance's name?*

The address of a member function is **independent** of the instance on which it is invoked on. From [class.mem](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.mem#17):

> The type of a non-static member function is an ordinary function type, and the type of a non-static data member is an ordinary object type. **There are no special member function types** or data member types.

(emphasis mine)

*For the purposes of overload resolution*, it is as if the non-static member function has an **implicit object parameter** of type `X&` if the member function is non-const and `const X&` if the member function is const. This *implicit object parameter* basically refers to the object on which it is invoked on.

---

Now coming to your second question:

> If so, what's the point of assigning &A::f, if it has no information about the instance?

**To identify** the member member `f` with the pointer `p`. For example, there can be more than one member functions in a class. Like `struct A{void f(); void g(int);int (A::*p)(int);};`. So by writing `a1.p = &A::f` you're telling the compiler that you want the address of `f` to be assigned to `a1.p`. Note also that the type of a non-static data member is also an ordinary object type.

The information about the instance(like on which instance to call) will be provided when dereferencing the pointer `p` as you've done in `(a1.*(a1.p))(5)` and `(a2.*(a1.p))(5)`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Is the "implicit object parameter" the same as `*this`? It's a bit confusing the "implicit object parameter" and the implicit first argument `this`.

Comment: @starriet The c++ standard only talks about *"implicit object parameter"* and not *"implicit this parameter"*. Note `this` is a prvalue of pointer type. But yes, `*this` is the object which is the implicit object parameter.

Comment: I tried checking both answers as accepted but doesn't work... Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @starriet Its fine. Whichever post helps you the most in clearing your concept, you're free to accept that. You're welcome :)